# Training and Testing of Algorithm in OD

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

Hi,
I am working on image processioning Specific on object detection algorithms .
Frequently I am coming across two terms called as training and testing of image .
I read some papers also about this, but not fully understood these terms in object detection.

Can some of us explain in easy language about these terms :

```
1)Training of Algo
2)Testing of Algo
```

Tr,
Ashwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most machine learning algorithms can be split into three phases. The training phase, the validation phase (optional) and the testing phase.

During training, the parameters of the algorithm are learned from a given training data set (in the case of supervised learning). Usually, this training data set consists of the algorithm's input and its output (so what the algorithm should do with a certain input). In object detection, this can be labeled images (what regions of an image correspond to what object). Since there are various algorithms, the learned parameters vary as well. In the case of neural networks, the edges' weights are being learned.

Testing is then the actual execution of the algorithm. You provide input and the algorithm calculates the output based on the learned parameters from the training phase. For object detection, the input might be an image, and the output might be each pixel's label.

Validation can be used after training in order to generalize parameters (i.e. avoid over-fitting).

Comment: ,I did not understand your statement : "Usually, this training data set consists of the algorithm's input and its output (so what the algorithm should do with a certain input)" ......If I am having input as well as output then what is the use of algorithm ..means what algo will learn from this ???

Comment: Most algorithms are only empty hulls that need parameters to work. The training phase can be used to learn things such as "if there is a white pixel next to a black one, this pixel belongs to object x". Of course only if the training images have this property. Then in testing, the algorithm can check this property and identify the pixel as object x or not.

Comment: Thanks Nico ..Now I understood that training is nothing but I am telling the algorithm that this is a CARrrrr ...This is not a CAR..etc..etc.Giving lots of input/images to understand the algorithm what is THE Object of Interest..In testing am checking my algorithm is checking the object as a car or non car item !!!!

Comment: You're welcome. I noticed that you haven't accepted an answer for any of your questions. Please make sure to accept the answer that solved your problem by clicking the check mark next to it. This lets other users know that the question is solved. Futhermore, you appreciate the answerer's help. You can appreciate answers further by up-voting them if you like.

Comment: Thanks for reminding this point ..Earlier I didn't have the enough credential to accept reply as solution for my query .But I think Now I can do that .. :)